# How to scaleX an object from the side, instead of centered in Animate CC HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

I managed to create a progress bar where I used **queue.on("progress", handleProgress);** to change the **scaleX** of a movieclip I named as bar_mc.

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.on("complete", handleComplete);
queue.on("progress", handleProgress);
queue.loadFile({
    id: "img",
    src: "images/image.jpg"
});



function handleComplete(evt) {
    console.log("Done!");
    createjs.Ticker.removeAllEventListeners();
};

function handleProgress(event) {
    console.log("Event Loading: " + (queue.progress.toFixed(2) * 100) + "%");
};


createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick.bind(this));

function handleTick(event) {
    console.log("ticking");
    this.bar_mc.scaleX = queue.progress;
};
```

It works, but it starts at the center like in **a)**:

[image]

How do I make it start from the side like in **b)**?

Also, this gave me an error when I tried it, but is there a way to put the **this.bar_mc.scaleX** into **function handleProgress(event)** instead of using a separate ticker function to animate bar_mc?

---

**Update:** I'm sure there is a way to do it using code, but I don't know how to do that. All I had to do was change the transformation point in Animate:
[image]

Now bar_mc scales from the side!

---

**Update 2:** Used Muhammed Maruf's insight about "fileprogress" and changed the code. Now it looks cleaner without having to use a separate ticker to make bar_mc scale.

Adding **var root** *before* the **queue.on** codes made me able to add **root.bar_mc.scaleX** into **function handleProgress(event)** without needing to change "progress":

```
var root = this;

root.bar_mc.scaleX = 0;

var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.on("complete", handleComplete);
queue.on("progress", handleProgress);
queue.loadFile({
    id: "img",
    src: "images/image.jpg"
});

function handleComplete(evt) {
    console.log("Done!");
    // do other stuff
};

function handleProgress(event) {
    console.log("Event Loading: " + (queue.progress.toFixed(2) * 100) + "%");
    root.bar_mc.scaleX = queue.progress;
};
```

Comment: looks like you answer your own question in less than 1 hour ... maybe this is not worth a question

Comment: Before posting, I tried to search for hours how to code it, but didn't find anything usable. It wasn't until I was reading a post in the Adobe Animate discussion forum about how to set width and height of symbol on stage, that I inadvertently found the transformation point. Hopefully this question will help other beginners like me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I updated the code.
Note that I used "fileload" instead of "complete" and "fileprogress" instead of "progress".

```js
var root = this;
root.bar_mc.scaleX = 0;
var source = "https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_49259263438_7e86e005b3_h_1280_960_nofilter.jpg?" + Math.random();
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.on("fileload", handleComplete);
queue.on("fileprogress", handleProgress);
queue.loadFile({
    id: "img",
    src: source
});

function handleComplete(evt) {
    console.log("Done!");
    console.log(queue.progress);
    root.bar_mc.scaleX = queue.progress;
};

function handleProgress(event) {
    console.log("Event Loading: " + (queue.progress.toFixed(2) * 100) + "%, " + queue.progress);
    root.bar_mc.scaleX = queue.progress;
};
```

Comment: Interesting. When I edited the code like this, "complete" and "progress" started working correctly. That means there is something wrong with the code.
You can use it in two ways.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I think having var root before the queue.on codes made it work. Previously, I added var root at the bottom after all the queue.on, which gave me errors.